# Using SUMIF and having a function in sum_range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column like:

```
156
2105 Kb
15 Kb
163
14 secs
65 Kb

etc
```

What I want to do is to put a function at the bottom of that column, and have it sum the numbers where the unit is `Kb` (so 2105 + 15 + 65 = answer). I got as far as:

```
=sumif(right(C200:C201,2),"Kb",LEFT(C200:C201,FIND(" ",C200:C201)-1))
```

Which fails for numerous reasons I think. I am guessing the sum_range in the SUMIF can not be a function. Happy to move away from SUM and IF if there is another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `SUMIF` cannot take processed ranges as the 'sum_column'. You could use `SUM` and `IF` separately in an array function:

```
=SUM(IF(RIGHT(C200:C201,3)=" Kb",LEFT(C200:C201,FIND(" ",C200:C201)-1)*1,0))
```

Array function means that after typing the formula in, you will need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for it to work.

Comment: Did you typo in there with the A1:A11?

Comment: @nzcoops Oops, yes. I replaced the wrong thing lol. I'll fix it.

Comment: Great, thanks very much for that. I had tried the SUM(IF()) as well, I didn't have the *1 on the end. Does having that trick excel into thinking it is a number hence getting it to sum them? (cause I was thinking I might be trying to get it to sum a text string).

Comment: @nzcoops Yup, that's exactly it. The `*1` will force convert the string/text to a number if it's possible and the result numbers can then be added.